# FlyingSaucerPdf , Greek alphabet, Helvetica

Tags: pdf, itext

In the project, I am working on we use Flying Saucer Pdf (9.0.9) & iText (2.1.7) for the creation of pdfs. By setting the Helvetica font, the characters of the Greek alphabet are not represented on the PDF. While changing the font Arial or Times New Roman the characters are represented correctly.

```
<div>
   <span style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
      <strong>
         <span style="font-size: 16pt;">&para;&micro;&alpha;&beta;&omega;&hearts;&micro;</span>
      </strong>
   </span>
</div>
```

Is there any workaround?

https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer

[image: Fonts added in the PDF]

Comment: A font may or may not include glyphs for a specific language. Do you believe that Helvetica does contain the characters you need?

Comment: I thought, these characters exist in the Helvetica font. The HTML representation of &alpha; works correctly in browser. But I don't know if browser use exactly Helvetica or other font. 
The difference between Arial and Helventica in my code is that Arial is manually added with Identity-H encoding, Helvetica is provided by the "PDF".

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to fix it by removing the preloaded Helvetica font. After that, I added a new Helvetica font. For testing I used https://www.cufonfonts.com/download/font/helvetica-255 font.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver;
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;
import org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.FSEntityResolver;

import com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont;

public class TestPdf2 {

    private static final String FILE_OUT = "src/test/resources/file.pdf";
    private static final String FONT_DIR = "src/test/resources/fonts/";
    private static final String[] FONT_FILES = {  //
            "Helvetica.ttf", "Helvetica-Bold.ttf", //
            "Helvetica-BoldOblique.ttf","helvetica-compressed-5871d14b6903a.otf", // 
            "helvetica-light-587ebe5a59211.ttf", "Helvetica-Oblique.ttf", //
            "helvetica-rounded-bold-5871d05ead8de.otf" };

    @Test
    public void buildHelvetica() throws Exception {
        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        ITextFontResolver fontRes = renderer.getFontResolver();
        
        Field fontFagliesField = ITextFontResolver.class.getDeclaredField("_fontFamilies");
        fontFagliesField.setAccessible(true);
        Map<String, ?> fontFamiliesMap = (Map<String, ?>) fontFagliesField.get(fontRes);
        fontFamiliesMap.remove("Helvetica");
        
        loadFont(fontRes);
        renderer.setDocument(getSampleDocument(), null);
        doRenderToPDF(renderer, FILE_OUT);
    }

    private static void loadFont(ITextFontResolver poF) throws Exception {
        for (String lsFontFile : FONT_FILES) {
            File lfFile = new File(FONT_DIR + lsFontFile);
            poF.addFont(lfFile.getAbsolutePath(), BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        }
    }

    private static void doRenderToPDF(ITextRenderer renderer, String pdf) throws Exception {
        try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(pdf)) {
            renderer.layout();
            renderer.createPDF(os);
        }
    }

    private static Document getSampleDocument() throws Exception {
        String lsSampleGreekDoc = //
            "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">" //
            + "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\r\n" //
            + "<head>\r\n" //
            + "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />\r\n" //
            + "<title>Test</title>\r\n"//
            + "</head>\r\n" //
            + "<body>\r\n" //
            + "<div style=\"font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 16pt;\">\r\n" //
            + " <del>Helvetica:</del>1&para; 2&micro; 3&alpha; 4&beta; 5&delta; 6&epsilon; " //
            + "7&zeta; 8&omega; 9&hearts; 10&micro; 11&Theta; 12&Xi; 13&Sigma;\r\n" //
            + "</div>\r\n" //
            + "</body>\r\n" //
            + "</html>"; //
        DocumentBuilder loDocumentBuilderXml = DocumentBuilderFactory.
                newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        loDocumentBuilderXml.setEntityResolver(FSEntityResolver.instance());
        ByteArrayInputStream loArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(lsSampleGreekDoc.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        return loDocumentBuilderXml.parse(loArrayInputStream);
    }

}
```